# Facebook API comments count

Tags: facebook, api

I searched everything here and didn't find the answer.

I'm calling FB API to get some posts analytics, but I find a strange behaviour. If I call for example

`134572506600855_2227601433964608/?fields=comments.limit(0).summary(true)`

I get comments total_count=100

`134572506600855_2227601433964608/comments?limit=0&summary=true&filter=stream`

I get comments total_count=575

this is because I added filter=stream, so it counts comments-of-comments like it does in the public counter. I need to use the first call because I get all the other details there and i want to avoid an API call for each post just to get the right comments total_count, but I cannot get filter=stream working with the first call,any suggestion?

Comment: Appending `.filter(stream)` to the end of the first one would seem like the logical thing to do … are you saying that didn’t work? (How? Do you get different data than expected, an error, …?)

Comment: it just works. Thank you!